# Vertical asymptote of $\frac {3x^2 - 18x - 81}{6x^2 - 54}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Vertical asymptote of  $f(x) = \frac {3x^2 - 18x - 81}{6x^2 - 54}$ is 3, but why not -3?

The original function is already expanded, however, factoring it out a little bit, we get:
$ \frac {3(x-9) (x+3)}{6(x-3)(x+3)}$

The way Salman Khan explained it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0ZgqB44Do4&t=4m30s) didn't really answer that question.

To find vertical asymptote of a rational function we see where it's undefined. And it's undefined when denominator is equal to $0$. As you can see from the factored version of the function, x = -3 does make the denominator equal to $0$!

Comment: I think a simple answer would be: because the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to -3 is 1 not infinity

Comment: Note that $x \to a$ means $x$ is close to but not equal to $a$.

Comment: But you also have the numerator equal to zero at -3 so $f(-3)=\frac{0}{0}$ and this does not tell you anything. You have to investigate the limit of the function as x tends to -3

Comment: @Chou What x - > a, what the hell does it have to do with anything?

Comment: @Tom so are you saying, that if you have a function 18x/x it will have no vertical asymptotes?

Comment: yes, 18x/x = 18 which is constant

Comment: @wilsonw Well, that's strange, if you plug in -3 into the numerator, it's going to yield $0$ (3 * 9 + 18*3 - 81 = $0$).

Comment: Oh, what I was saying is different from "$f(-3) = 1$"... what I mean is "for each $\delta<|x-3|$, I can find an $\epsilon$ such that $|f(x)-1| <\epsilon$". So if you plot the graph of $f(x)$, you will have a curve near $x=-3$, but at that point where $x=-3$ you will have a hole there (instead of a curve going up or down infinitely)

Comment: I think you have misconception. You seem to think that a rational function has a vertical asymptote wherever it's denominator is zero. That's not true. The numerator might be zero, too, so you have to work harder to find out what the limiting value of the function is. Sometimes the work is not too hard -- all you have to do is cancel some common factor in the numerator and denominator (as in this case).

Comment: @wilsonw so how does one determine whether a point is a removable discontinuity/"a hole" or a valid critical point? For instance here, how did you figure out that x = -3 is a removable discontinuity?

Comment: To see if the limit is infinity: if $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=a$, but you have the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $a$ to be $L$, then the curve would look good near the point $(a,L)$.

Comment: Or, if you can cancel out all the $(x-a)$ factors in the denominator from the numerator, then the discontinuity would be removable.

Comment: But the converse is not true: some functions like $\frac{\sin x}x$ also contains a removable discontinuity...

Comment: @wilsonw I still don't see how you differentiate critical point from removable discontinuity.

Comment: @dramadeur Critical point is another thing. You have to differentiate the function first, and then take the *numerator* to be $0$ not denominator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function $f$ is just a slightly disguised form of
$$
g(x) = \frac{x-9}{2(x-3)}
$$
So, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to -3}f(x) = g(-3) = \frac{-12}{-12} = 1
$$
So, there is no vertical asymptote at $x=-3$. Actually, the original function $f$ is *undefined* at $x=-3$ because its defining formula gives $0/0$. So there is a "hole" in its graph, if you like. But that's not the same thing as the graph shooting off to infinity (which is what you get at an asymptote).

Here's what the graph of $f$ looks like

[image]

The little hollow circle at $(-3,1)$ is meant to indicate that the function $f$ is undefined when $x=-3$.

Comment: In your simplified form, yes. But not in the original function, when x = -3, both the numerator and the denominator will be equal to $0$.

Comment: Well, if you think the original $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=-3$, try calculating some values of $f(x)$ when $x$ is very close to $-3$. Do you see those values shooting off to infinity???

Comment: I don't think so. The function gets close to 1 as $x$ gets close to $-3$.

Comment: How did you so quickly determine that the original function doesn't shoot off to infinity as x approaches -3, but does when x approaches 3?

Comment: You can just observe that the $x+3$ cancels in the numerator and denominator. Once the $x+3$ is gone from the denominator, there is no danger of shooting off to infinity. Or, just graph the function $g$, and bear in mind that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal, even when $x$ is very close to $-3$ (though not when $x$ is actually equal to $-3$).

Answer (score 4):

A vertical asymptote of a function is a line $x=k$ being approximated by the function as $x\to k^{\pm}$, meaning that it has to go to $\pm\infty$ in that point.  Thus, $x=-3$ is not a vertical asymptote of your $f$ because $$\require\cancel \lim\limits_{x\to -3}  \frac {3(x-9) \cancel{(x+3)}}{6(x-3)\cancel{(x+3)}}=\frac{-36}{-36}=1.$$

In other words, a function has a vertical asymptote in a point of discontinuity of second kind, whereas $x=-3$ is a point of removable discontinuity (third kind) of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

A line with equation $x=k$ is an asymptote for a function $f$ when 
$$
\lim_{x\to k^{\pm}} f(x) =\pm\infty,
$$
meaning that at least one of the four combinations occurs.

For rational functions of the form $f(x)=p(x)/q(x)$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials, the condition $q(k)=0$ is a *necessary* condition for $f$ having $x=k$ as asymptote. Indeed, if $q(k)\ne0$, the function $f$ is continuous at $k$, which implies that $\lim_{x\to k}f(x)=f(k)$ exists and is finite.

However, the condition is not *sufficient*: the simple example of $f(x)=2x/x$ shows this. It's true that the denominator vanishes at $0$, but
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=2
$$
so none of the four combinations above occurs.

Your case is very similar:
$$
f(x) = \frac {3x^2 - 18x - 81}{6x^2 - 54}=\frac{(x-9)(x+3)}{2(x-3)(x+3)}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to -3}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{x-9}{2(x-3)}=\frac{-12}{-12}=1
$$
and none of the four combinations mentioned at the start occurs.

You can observe that $\lim_{x\to-3}(3x^2 - 18x - 81)=0$, so $\lim_{x\to-3}f(x)$ is in the *indeterminate form* $0/0$, meaning that you can't draw conclusions about the limit without further work (in this case, factoring out the common factor $x+3$).

It *is* possible that both numerator and denominator vanish at a point $k$ and still the line $x=k$ be an asymptote for the function. Consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2-2x+1}=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x-1)^2}
$$
Then both numerator and denominator vanish at $1$, but
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{x-2}{x-1}=\infty,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{x-2}{x-1}=-\infty,
$$
so $x=1$ *is* an asymptote for $f$.

Comment: Hm, so I guess to find a vertical asymptote, one should look at the factored form of the function?

Comment: @dramadeur You have to compute the limits from the left and from the right (or, if it exists, just the full limit). The case of rational function is easy, because if numerator and denominator vanish at a point $k$, you can factor out $x-k$.